# Instance method '-presentViewController:animated' not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm fairly new to this, so bear with me. I have 2 errors left to fix in my code. In both cases my instance methods are not found:

```
-(IBAction)goFlipSide {
    NSLog(@"goFlipSide has been called:");
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil];

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    //This method gets fired when the user clicks done on the modal FlipsideViewController.  This is different
    //than the viewWillAppear.
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;
    /*
    if (self.goViewSuccess == TRUE) {
        //if the goViewSuccess boolean is set to YES - then we can load the load the goViewController
        NSLog(@"goViewSuccess is YES");
        [self loadGoViewController];
    }
    */
}
```

Both instance methods not found are: `presentViewController:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:`.

Comment: Who is `self` (in which class is those methods)?

Comment: Look at the docs for `UIViewController`. Look at the method that begins with `presentViewController`. You are missing an argument.

Comment: steinm10: According to me you are writing you code in iOS6.1.  `presentViewController:controller animated:YES` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES` methods are deprecated in iOS6.1

Answer (score 4):

What class is `self`?  Those methods are only found on `UIViewController`.  The full selectors are:

- `presentViewController:animated:completion:`
- `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`

Try adding the completion block argument.

Comment: If you don't need a completion block just pass `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is supposed to be this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

or if you want something when its done,

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
//do stuff
}];
```

And for the other one

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```